Performing a rotation on an avl tree
Does anyone know how to perform the right left rotation on this avl tree?

I moved 45 up to be the root, the 50 to be the right child, and the 40 to be  the left child but where do the children of 45 go? Any help would be appreciated.

That looks like a rotation being performed to make 50 the new root, not 45.  50's left child becomes the old root (40), the old root's right child becomes 50's former left child (45).  Once you do that, 45 becomes a direct child of the root, and could then be rotated to become the root - in other words, move it up one step at a time.

This is the tree:
           _ 40 _
          /      \
        30        50
       /  \      /  \
     20    35  45    60
              /  \     \
            41    46    70
              \
               42

The root is unbalanced, and as on the heavy (right) side the inner grandchild (45) is higher than the outer grandchild (60), a double rotation is needed. First rotate 50 to the right, lifting 45 up:
           __ 40 __
          /        \
        30        _ 45 _
       /  \      /      \
     20    35  41        50
                 \      /  \
                  42  46    60
                              \
                               70

And then rotate 40 to the left, lifting 45 again:
           _ 45 _
          /      \
        40        50
       /  \      /  \
     30    41  46    60
    /  \     \         \
  20    35    42        70

That's it.
